# add an image behind video that has a moving camera in python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to add an image in a video that has a moving camera (for example a basketball game video), but I want the image to not follow the camera or be still at the starting point added. how if with opencv?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I see to do this is to simply write over the pixels of the video. A frame of the video is basically a 2-dimensional array of frames, so by simply replacing some of these frames with the frames from the image(which is also a 2-dimensional array of pixels).

EDIT:

Since I've been asked to provide some code, this should work(if the image is smaller than the frame):

```
import cv2

while True:
   for x in range(0, len(frame)):   
      for c in range(0, len(frame[x])):       
        if(c < len(image[0])):          
           frame[x][c] = image[x][c]       
        else:          
           break

   cv2.cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
   k = cv2.waitKey(33)
   if k == 27:
      break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: can you provide a sample code?
because I am new to this. thank you

Comment: This won't work. Question clearly states Camera is moving, but the image needs to be still.